# Focus a set of buttons after clicked once in tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I had a 4 rows of  three buttons each.

Tailwind play [link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0DG4u1aykp)

### What I want is

that when I click any ONE of the 3 buttons in the first row, then click any ONE of the 3 buttons in the next row, and then for the last two rows also , if I click any one button in these rows .

They all the clicked buttons should remained highlighted.

How can I achieve this in tailwind css.

### My research

I had searched and found `focused` state but as soon as I click any button in the second row , the highlight thing vanished in the button selected in previous row.

### My Code

```
<div class="relative flex min-h-screen flex-col justify-center overflow-hidden bg-gray-50 py-6 sm:py-12 space-y-6">
  <div class="bg-slate-50 px-28 ">
    <button class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-5 py-2.5 focus:bg-green-500">Login21</button>
    <button class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-5 py-2.5 focus:bg-green-500">Login22</button>
    <button class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-5 py-2.5 focus:bg-green-500">Login23</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-slate-50 px-28 ">
    <button class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-5 py-2.5 focus:bg-green-500">Login31</button>
    <button class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-5 py-2.5 focus:bg-green-500">Login32</button>
    <button class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-5 py-2.5 focus:bg-green-500">Login33</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-slate-50 px-28 ">
    <button class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-5 py-2.5 focus:bg-green-500">Login41</button>
    <button class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-5 py-2.5 focus:bg-green-500">Login42</button>
    <button class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-5 py-2.5 focus:bg-green-500">Login43</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-slate-50 px-28 ">
    <button class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-5 py-2.5 focus:bg-green-500">Login51</button>
    <button class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-5 py-2.5 focus:bg-green-500">Login52</button>
    <button class="bg-indigo-400 text-white px-5 py-2.5 focus:bg-green-500">Login53</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tailwind play [link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0DG4u1aykp)

### Is it possible with tailwindCSS or css only ?

Comment: You have to toggle the class in which it is highlighted

Comment: can you clarify it?

Comment: Are you allowed to use javascript?

Comment: no my friend because I had a lot of buttons, else I use states?

Comment: Well i could be easier with js. May be 5 lines max..

Comment: yeah I am also thinking of using states (as I am using nextjs) but I was hoping for a pure tailwind css answer

Comment: You can't do this with just :focus or event :focus-within because only one element can have focus at a time. I think your best option would be to toggle a class with JS when you click the buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fix it by input[type=radio]

see HTML and CSS in Tailwind play: https://play.tailwindcss.com/ALXtlFabvI